# NextAuth refresh token with Azure AD

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth

Since the default valid time for an access token is 1 hour, I am trying to get refresh tokens to work  in my application. I have been stuck with this problem for a couple of weeks now, and cannot seem to fix it. I have verified my `refreshAccessToken(accessToken)` function to work (where `accessToken` is an object with the expired token, the refresh token and some other stuff).

I pinpointed the issue to the `async session()` function. While in the `async jwt()` function, refreshAccessToken gets called, the `async session()` function still results in an error, because the parameter **`token` is undefined**. This results in the error `cannot read property accessToken from undefined` (since `token.accessToken` is on the first line). How could I solve this, and somehow make the function `async session()` wait for the access token to refresh, before sending it to the client, together with all other information (groups, username etc.)?

```js
/**
 * All requests to /api/auth/* (signIn, callback, signOut, etc.) will automatically be handled by NextAuth.js.
 */

import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import AzureAD from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

async function refreshAccessToken(accessToken) {
  try {
    const url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/02cd5db4-6c31-4cb1-881d-2c79631437e8/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: `grant_type=refresh_token`
      + `&client_secret=${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET}`
      + `&refresh_token=${accessToken.refreshToken}`
      + `&client_id=${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}`
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        return {
          ...accessToken,
          accessToken: res.access_token,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + res.expires_in * 1000,
          refreshToken: res.refresh_token ?? accessToken.refreshToken, // Fall backto old refresh token
        }
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    return {
      ...accessToken,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureAD({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "offline_access openid profile email Application.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All " +
            "Group.ReadWrite.All GroupMember.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadWrite.All"
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, account, profile}) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
      if (account && profile) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.accessTokenExpires = account.expires_at * 1000;
        token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token;

        token.id = profile.oid; // For convenience, the user's OID is called ID.
        token.groups = profile.groups;
        token.username = profile.preferred_username;
      }

      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        return token;
      }

      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session({session, token}) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.groups = token.groups;
      session.user.username = token.username;

      const splittedName = session.user.name.split(" ");
      session.user.firstName = splittedName.length > 0 ? splittedName[0] : null;
      session.user.lastName = splittedName.length > 1 ? splittedName[1] : null;

      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I tried searching everywhere online, but it is hard to even find people using Azure AD with NextAuth at all (NOT the B2C version, but the B2B/organisations version).

**TLDR: Using the refreshToken to get a new accessToken works, but NextAuth does not pass this token to the frontend, and instead throws an error, since in `async session()`, token is undefined.**

Comment: your code helped me solve an issue, you might want to change the fetch URL and turn the tenantID into a variable. my code was trying to connect to the HeatWaves tenant since i overlooked that part :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the provided code, I made the mistake of mixing async with promises (credits to @balazsorban44 on GitHub). This means that the `return` statement in the `.then` returns the value to where the fetch request was initiated, instead of it returning a value from the function `refreshAccessToken()` as a whole. I moved away from using promises and only used an async function:

```java
    const req = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: `grant_type=refresh_token`
      + `&client_secret=${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET}`
      + `&refresh_token=${accessToken.refreshToken}`
      + `&client_id=${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}`
    })

    const res = await req.json();
```

Comment: Perfect, got refresh token flow working with my Custom Sanity Adapter + Azure AD B2B -- thanks man!

For anyone else who is using typescript, you'll want to set the parameter type for `refreshAccessToken` to the next-auth `JWT` type. The Response returned by the initial fetch to the token endpoint is 

declare const refreshAccessTokenResponseShape: {

        token_type: string;

        scope: string;

        expires_in: number;

        ext_expires_in: number;

        access_token: string;

        refresh_token: string;

        id_token: string;

}