# how to get Azure AD refresh token in Next-Auth / Auth.js

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, next-auth, azure-ad-graph-api

have been looking for 2 days how to get the refresh token, with this configuration, but in response refresh token is missing.

want to get new refresh token automatically so user not have to sign in again.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: `${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}`,
      clientSecret: `${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope:
            "offline_access openid profile email Application.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All " +
            "Group.ReadWrite.All GroupMember.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadWrite.All",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin

      console.log("JWT token", token);

      if (account) {
        console.log("account", token);
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};
```

This is the response i get

```
JWT token {
  name: 'name',
  picture: null,
  sub: 'X6_CatcEVmqbZlsN91oFDhdV3QUVe-....',
  accessToken: 'token',
  iat: 1708110693,
  exp: 1710702693,
  jti: '8eb36962-5998-4950-b0c9-7...'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I registered one Entra ID application and granted below **API permissions** based on your scopes:

[image]

Now, I added `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad` as redirect URI in **Web** platform:

[image]

Initially, I too got **same results** without refresh token when I ran your code in my environment:

```js
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: `${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}`,
      clientSecret: `${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'offline_access openid profile email Application.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All ' +
            'Group.ReadWrite.All GroupMember.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadWrite.All',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],

callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
    // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin

    console.log("JWT token", token);

    if (account) {
      console.log("account", token);
      token.accessToken = account.access_token;
    }
    return token;
  },
},
};
```

[image]

When I ran below *modified* code and logged in again with same account, I got the **refresh token** in response successfully like this:

```js
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad'

let accountInfoProcessed = false;

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: `${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID}`,
      clientSecret: `${process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'offline_access openid profile email Application.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All ' +
            'Group.ReadWrite.All GroupMember.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadWrite.All',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin

      // Process account info only if it hasn't been processed before
      if (account && !accountInfoProcessed) {
        console.log("Account Info:", account);
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token;
        console.log("Refresh Token:", token.refreshToken);

        // Set the flag to true to indicate that account info has been processed
        accountInfoProcessed = true;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};
```

[image]

In your case, make sure to grant **`offline_access`** permission in your application and sign in again with modified code to get refresh token.

**References:**

[next.js - NextAuth refresh token with Azure AD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75164721/nextauth-refresh-token-with-azure-ad)

[javascript - Missing Azure AD refresh token in Next-Auth / Auth.js - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421945/missing-azure-ad-refresh-token-in-next-auth-auth-js?rq=2)

Comment: Awesome Thanks a lot, added `offline_access ` permission and worked like a charm, why we need to set flag for `accountInfoProcessed` ?

Comment: In my case, I repeatedly got the account info with tokens. So, I kept flag as a break to print account info with tokens only once.